# "use of undeclared identifier" error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been following a tutorial about parsing json with Xcode but have come across issues that i cant resolve.  I suspect they are because the tutorial is using 5.1 and i am using 6.1

AppDelegate.m 
unused variable 'navController'
use of undeclared identifier 'navController'
See below

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m
Expected method body
Use of undeclared identifier 'theData'

```
- (void)connection:NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `navController` outside the if statement:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController* navController;

    navController = nil;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

As an alternative, you could move the creation of `navController` so it only needs to be done in one place:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

For the other error, you are missing '(' before NSURLConnection.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `navController` out of `if-else`:

```
UINavigationController *navController;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
}
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```